# ´class´ does not contains a definition for ´method´ but it´s there

Tags: c#, virtual

I have a class as follows

```
public class EntityBase
{
    // other code
    public virtual void SetDataContext(IDataContext context) { throwNotImplemented("SetDefaultDataContext"); }

    protected void throwNotImplemented( string mname )
    {
        throw new Exception( String.Format( "Method {0} is not implemented") );                
    }
}
```

The purpose of throwNotImplemented is to force derived classes to implement the virtual methods as if they were abstract.

Then I have a class that references EntityBase, as follows

```
public class BasePresenter<IDataContextFactory, IDataContext, EntityBase> 
        where IDataContextFactory : class, new() where IDataContext : class where EntityBase : class
{
    public IDataContext dataContext;
    public BasePresenter( IDataContext dc, EntityBase sample)
    {
        dataContext = dc;
        sample.SetDataContext(dataContext);
    }
// more code 
}
```

The compiler is stuck in this error:

'EntityBase' does not contain a definition for 'SetDataContext' and no extension method ... etc

Who or what is wrong?

TIA

Comment: It’d be a lot easier to reason about your example if you followed the accepted naming conventions for your generic parameters, e.g., each should be prefixed with `T` (like TDataContext).  If you did that, the answer might even be obvious to you.

Comment: @MikeStrobel The important generic parameter is (precisely) EntityBase, so the conventions don´t take place, IMHO. In fact, what could be obvious to me if I followed the naming convention? Thank you

Comment: @MikeStrobel changed the generic parameters to "conventions" and nothing different happens with the compiler´s error.

Comment: As the other said, using the word "EntityBase" as the name of a generic parameter (or what is the proper term?) causes massive ambguity (is the generic type placeholder or the actuall type meant?). Basically you have this issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLwVKYS-iSs If you have changed it, please update teh question.

Comment: @Christopher Ok, but I "need" an "EntityBase" materialised instance as the generic parameter. I cannot see how I could define that otherwise. Thank you.

Comment: @Christopher by now, I eliminated EntityBase as a generic parameter and it compiles OK. But this is a tiny experiment. May be this work for a full blown libeary. Thank you.

Comment: If you define the Generic Parameter/Type Placeholder (still not sure what the proper term for them is) "T", you can then constrain it as normal. As for this working for a full blown library: The entirety of the .NET Framework uses single character type placeholders, starting with T. List[T] is a very common way to refer to generic classes. If it works for the largest .NET Library on the planet (the Framework itself), it should work for whatever you are planning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use EntityBase as a generic type parameter in the <> and constrain it to be a decendant of the type "class". So any class. Therefore the compiler can not know whether EntityBase is an actual decentant of your EntityBase class. What you probably want to do is simply strip the EntityBase generic type from between the <>.

Comment: My bad. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Inside your generic class, the identifier `EntityBase` represents a generic parameter.  This hides the class named `EntityBase` from scope.  In particular, this means that

> I have a class that references EntityBase

is wrong.

Since the only constraint on the generic parameter `EntityBase` is `: class`, the only members you can use are those found on `object`, such as `GetHashCode()`, `GetType()`, and `ToString()`.